# Edit of Remarks rejected due to proposed changed on an example

Tags: discussion, bug, documentation, documentation-editor

I edited the *Remarks* section of the C++ string topic on SO:

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/48280?draftId=41328

This was **Rejected due to a conflict with another proposed change**:

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/48274

Is this expected behavior? The two proposed changes targets completely different parts of the topic, and still, they are in conflict? This seems like a really weird behavior to me.

Comment: Known bug that has already been posted numerous times

Comment: @charlietfl Links? We need a canonical post on this.